# asp mvc3, post form with hidden input containing json array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a form like this one :

```
<form id="orderForm">
    <input name="Customer" value="Mr.Test" />
    <input name="ProductLines" value='[{"Product":{"Name":"Orange","Price":"10"},"amount":"2","total":"20"}, {"Product":{"Name":"Apple","Price":"5"},"amount":"3","total":"15"}]' />
</form>
```

and controller with view models:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(OrderViewModel vm)
{
    //...
}

public class OrderViewModel
{
    public OrderViewModel() { ProductLines = new List<OrderProductViewModel>(); }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderProductViewModel> ProductLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProductViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to post this form with jquery

```
      $.post('@Url.Action("Save")', $("#orderForm").serialize(), function (data) {//...}, "json");
```

and get ProductLines collection filled on server side. (currently it's always empty)

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posting object needs to be converted in json object and posted with content type json. 
Try the following it might help

```
var results = {};
$.each($("#orderForm").serializeArray(), function (index, item) {
    results[item.name] = item.value;
});
results.ProductLines = $.parseJSON(results.ProductLines);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(results),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```